# How to convert a Blogger user name to numeric ID

Tags: gdata-api, blogger, zend-gdata

When working with the [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/intl/en_US/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html) the user ID is expected to be numeric. I found out my numeric ID by looking at the URL for my Blogger profile page. However, I want my users to be able to use their usual Blogger user name. So:

1. Is there a way to convert Blogger
   user names to numeric user IDs?
2. Is there a way to pass in user names
   instead of IDs to the Blogger API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but in most use cases you don't need to explicitly know this information because the `authToken` will take care of resolving these issues for you if you use the default URLs with the API.  But, in the interest of providing an answer in case you really do need to know this:

1. After the user authenticates, just request some information, like the list of blogs, and you'll be able to extract the ID number from your choice of several places in the response.
2. Not really, except that during login you use the username.  Otherwise you need to use either default, assuming an active `authToken`, or the ID to reference a particular user's Blogger content.

Comment: Actually my users never authenticate. They just give me the user id and then I request public information. However I want to simplify this for them by requesting only their user name. Thanks.

Comment: Oh.  In that case I don't think that there is a way to do that since the API is really designed for getting access to parts of Blogger that require authentication.  Without authenticating first you can't really do anything with it.